# Delay in loading banner ads from admob

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, adview

I've been adding admob banner ads into my android app using the standard code available in the get started section on their website. Everything is fine except there's a few second delay after the activity starts before the ad is loaded. I've seen people having the same problem and asking about preloading the ad however there's no clear solution available anywhere. I know most apps on the market don't have this delay so my question is how to work around it? I could load all the ads into an array list in my loading activity and store them in shared preferences however I have read that it's discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read and understood there is not much you can do about it. It does take time. One solution that I have seen is

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Log.i(TAG," Interstitial Add :Loaded");
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Could not load Interstitial Add");
    }
}
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This is for Interstitial adds but same goes for banner ads well. Probably hide you add section and make it visible only when ads are loaded.

**Note** :  This is the suggestion I got when I had similar doubt. **But I have heard accounts getting banned due to this type of code**, not sure about it's reasons though. So please do some groundwork before adding this code to your app.

Comment: another issue that I'm having is that these ads make my app quite laggy...for something so popular and endorsed by Google I'd expect much better performance, so either I'm doing something wrong or this is a huge disappointment

Comment: and I'm testing on a Note 3, hate to think what the performance would be like on weaker devices